# Make images Ease out on hover out

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I made a small image gallery when hovering an image it enlarges, I wish that the images will minimize back with some ease and not immediately when I hover out, i can that be achieved ?

here is the code:

```
#main{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 720px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border-color:silver


}

#title{
    position:relative;
    width:679px;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    left:-4px;
    top:121px;
    border: solid;
    background-color:silver;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:-100;


}
#MainImage{
    background-image: url('zlf246.jpg');
    position:relative;
    width: 680px;
    height: 560px;
    margin-left: 155px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:-200;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border-color:silver

}

    #PicGallaryR {
    width: 150px;
    height: 560px;
    float: right;
    direction: rtl;

}

    #PicGallaryL {
    width: 150px;
    height: 560px;
    float: left;

}

    #PicGallaryB {
    width: 993px;
    height: 145px;

}
    a, .imgArt {
    width:150px;
    height:140px;

}

</style>
    <script>

$(function () {
$(".imgArt").bind("mouseenter", function () {

    var n = $(this).clone();
    var of = $(this).offset();
    var isRight = $(this).closest("div").attr("id") == "PicGallaryR";
    var options = {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: of.top,
        margin: 0
    };
    if (isRight) options["right"] = 918;
    else options["left"] = of.left;
    n.css(options)
        .appendTo($("#main"))
        .animate({
        width: 300,
        height: 280
    });

    n.bind("mouseleave", function () {
        $(this).stop(true).remove()
    });
});

}); 
    </script>
</head>


<body>  

    <div id="main">
        <div id="PicGallaryL">
    <a href="#"><img class="imgArt" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2jb04z4.png" ></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imgArt" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2jb04z4.png" ></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imgArt" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2jb04z4.png" ></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imgArt" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2jb04z4.png" ></a>
        </div>
    <div id="PicGallaryR">
    <a href="#"><img class="imgArt" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2jb04z4.png" ></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imgArt" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2jb04z4.png" ></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imgArt" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2jb04z4.png" ></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imgArt" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2jb04z4.png" ></a>

    </div>
    <div id="MainImage">
        <div id="title">Sterling silver ethnic filigree ring, Yemenite Art</div>

    </div>
    <div id="PicGallaryB">
    <a href="#"><img class="imgArt" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2jb04z4.png" ></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imgArt" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2jb04z4.png" ></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imgArt" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2jb04z4.png" ></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imgArt" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2jb04z4.png" ></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imgArt" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2jb04z4.png" ></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="imgArt" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2jb04z4.png" ></a>


    </div>


</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do that by using easing property in animate function.. Here is the [full documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)..

Example 1:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    width: [ "toggle", "swing" ],
    height: [ "toggle", "swing" ],
    opacity: "toggle"
  }, 5000, "linear", function() {
    $( this ).after( "<div>Animation complete.</div>" );
  });
});
```

Example 2:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    width: "toggle",
    height: "toggle"
  }, {
    duration: 5000,
    specialEasing: {
      width: "linear",
      height: "easeOutBounce"
    },
    complete: function() {
      $( this ).after( "<div>Animation complete.</div>" );
    }
  });
});
```

**EDITED:**

```
.animate({
    width: 300,
    height: 280
}, 300, "linear");
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions, for some reason it doesn't work properly, I need to implement it on the code above

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the only point missing is that before binding `.animate({})` to your current object, you have to save the original width and height.

That gives something like this :

```
var originalWidth = $(this).css('width');
var originalHeight = $(this).css('height');

n.bind("mouseleave", function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: originalWidth,
        height: originalHeight
    }, 300, "linear");
});
```

I made a JSFiddle so you can try it: http://jsfiddle.net/jpreynat/4e6po8z3/

Comment: it works, but has many bugs! :(
it seems we must enter `remove()` somehow in order to get rid of the duplicated image